# Sum an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a ruby array of 3 hashes. Each peace has information about report_data (consumption of 2 types of energy) and monthes_data (same for each). Please see the code below.

```
arr = [{:report_data=>
  [{:type=>
      {"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"},
    :data=>[10, 20, 30, 40]},
    {:type=>
      {"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},
    :data=>[20, 30, 40, 50]}],
  :monthes_data=>
    {:monthes=>
      ["jan", "feb"]},

 {:report_data=>
  [{:type=>
      {"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"},
    :data=>[15, 25, 35, 45]},
    {:type=>
      {"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},
    :data=>[25, 35, 45, 55]}],
  :monthes_data=>
    {:monthes=>
      ["jan", "feb"]},

 {:report_data=>
  [{:type=>
      {"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"},
    :data=>[17, 27, 37, 47]},
    {:type=>
      {"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},
    :data=>[27, 37, 47, 57]}],
  :monthes_data=>
    {:monthes=>
      ["jan", "feb"]}]
```

I'm new to Ruby. Please help me to sum all the data by energy types. In the end I want to have one hash with report_data and monthes_data. I need the result look like:

```
{:report_data=>
  [{:type=>
      {:"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"},
    :data=>[42, 72, 102, 132]},
    {:type=>
      {"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"}},
    :data=>[72, 102, 132, 162]}],
  :monthes_data=>
    {:monthes=>
      ["jan", "feb"]}}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question look like *write-code-for-me-im-too-lazy-to-try*.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Ruby, I need a hint, because I don't know where to start :(

Comment: Try something it's very easy. Just use google https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ruby%20hash%20sum%20elements

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the question (before the edit). It's clear and complete with a non-obvious solution, which is more than I can say for many of the questions posted on SO. +1 [The only suggestion for improvement I can make is to set a variable equal to the array (e.g, `arr = [{:report_data=>...]`), so that readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without defining it.)  Those who downvoted should give their reasons for doing so. I hope it's not because the OP has not shown code. He/she has explained why that has not been provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
def convert(arr)
  { :months_data=>arr.first[:months_data],
    :report_data=>arr.map { |h| h[:report_data] }.
      transpose.
      map { |d| { :type=>d.first[:type] }.
        merge(:data=>d.map { |g| g[:data] }.transpose.map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }) }
  }
end
```

**Example**

Half the battle in problems such as this one is visualizing the data. It's much clearer, imo, when written like this:

```
arr = [
  {:report_data=>[
     {:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[10, 20, 30, 40]},
     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[20, 30, 40, 50]}
     ],
   :months_data=>{:months=>["jan", "feb"]}
  },    
  {:report_data=>[
     {:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[15, 25, 35, 45]},
     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[25, 35, 45, 55]}
     ],
   :months_data=>{:months=>["jan", "feb"]}
  },    
  {:report_data=>[
     {:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[17, 27, 37, 47]},
     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[27, 37, 47, 57]}],
   :months_data=>{:months=>["jan", "feb"]}
  }
]
```

Let's try it:

```
convert(arr)
  #=> {:months_data=>{:months=>["jan", "feb"]},
  #    :report_data=>[
  #      {:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[42, 72, 102, 132]},
  #      {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[72, 102, 132, 162]}
  #    ]
  #   }
```

**Explanation**

The first thing I did is concentrate on computing the sums, so I converted this to the values of `:report_data`. That key, and the key-value pair of months' data, which is the same for all elements (hashes) of `arr`, can be added back in later.

```
b = arr.map { |h| h[:report_data] }
  #=> [
  #    [{:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[10, 20, 30, 40]},
  #     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[20, 30, 40, 50]}
  #    ],
  #    [{:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[15, 25, 35, 45]},
  #     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[25, 35, 45, 55]}
  #    ],
  #    [{:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[17, 27, 37, 47]},
  #     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[27, 37, 47, 57]}
  #    ]
  #   ]
```

If you are not certain that the elements of each array will be sorted by `"id"`, you could write:

```
b = arr.map { |h| h[:report_data].sort_by { |g| g[:type]["id"] } }

c = b.transpose
  #=> [
  #    [{:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[10, 20, 30, 40]},
  #     {:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[15, 25, 35, 45]},
  #     {:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[17, 27, 37, 47]}
  #    ],
  #    [{:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[20, 30, 40, 50]},
  #     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[25, 35, 45, 55]},
  #     {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[27, 37, 47, 57]}
  #    ]
  #   ] 

e = c.map {|d| { :type=>d.first[:type] }.
      merge(:data=>d.map { |g| g[:data] }.transpose.map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }) }
  #=> [{:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[42, 72, 102, 132]},
  #    {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"}      , :data=>[72, 102, 132, 162]}]
```

Lastly, we need to put the put the key `:report_data` back in and add the months' data:

```
{ :months_data=>arr.first[:months_data], :report_data=>e }
  #=> {:months_data=>{:months=>["jan", "feb"]},
  #    :report_data=>[
  #      {:type=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"}, :data=>[42, 72, 102, 132]},
  #      {:type=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},       :data=>[72, 102, 132, 162]}
  #    ]
  #   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{:report_data=>
  [{:type=>
      {"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"},
    :data=>[10, 20, 30, 40]},
    {:type=>
      {"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},
    :data=>[20, 30, 40, 50]}],
  :monthes_data=>
    {:monthes=>
      ["jan", "feb"]}},

 {:report_data=>
  [{:type=>
      {"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"},
    :data=>[15, 25, 35, 45]},
    {:type=>
      {"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},
    :data=>[25, 35, 45, 55]}],
  :monthes_data=>
    {:monthes=>
      ["jan", "feb"]}},

 {:report_data=>
  [{:type=>
      {"id"=>1, "name"=>"electricity"},
    :data=>[17, 27, 37, 47]},
    {:type=>
      {"id"=>2, "name"=>"water"},
    :data=>[27, 37, 47, 57]}],
  :monthes_data=>
    {:monthes=>
      ["jan", "feb"]}}]


acc = {}
arr.each do
    |e| e[:report_data].each_with_index do
        |e, idx| 
        type = e[:type]['id']
        e[:data].each_with_index do 
            |e, idx|
            acc[type] = [] if not acc[type]
            acc[type][idx] = (acc[type][idx] or 0) + e  
        end
    end
end
p acc
```

outputs

```
{1=>[42, 72, 102, 132], 2=>[72, 102, 132, 162]}
```

You should be able to reformat this into your record

Answer (score 0):

For clarity I've reformatted the input array and removed the `:monthes_data` key, since that seems to be unrelated to your question. Here's our data:

### TL;DR

```ruby
def zip_sum(arr1, arr2)
  return arr2 if arr1.nil?
  arr1.zip(arr2).map {|a, b| a + b }
end

def sum_report_data(arr)
  arr.flat_map do |item|
    item[:report_data].map {|datum| datum.values_at(:type, :data) }
  end
  .reduce({}) do |sums, (type, data)|
    sums.merge(type => data) do |_, old_data, new_data|
      zip_sum(old_data, new_data)
    end
  end
  .map {|type, data| { type: type, data: data } }
end
```

```ruby
p sum_report_data(arr)
# =>
[ { type: { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" }, data: [ 42, 72, 102, 132 ] },
  { type: { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" }, data: [ 72, 102, 132, 162 ] }
]
```

### Explanation

```ruby
arr = [
  { report_data: [
      { type: { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" },
        data: [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ]
      },
      { type: { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" },
        data: [ 20, 30, 40, 50 ]
      }
    ]
  },

  { report_data: [
      { type: { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" },
        data: [ 15, 25, 35, 45 ]
      },
      { type: { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" },
        data: [ 25, 35, 45, 55 ]
      }
    ]
  },

  { report_data: [
      { type: { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" },
        data: [ 17, 27, 37, 47 ]
      },
      { type: { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" },
        data: [ 27, 37, 47, 57 ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Step 1

First, let's define a helper method to sum the values of two arrays:

```ruby
def zip_sum(arr1, arr2)
  return arr2 if arr1.nil?
  arr1.zip(arr2).map {|a, b| a + b }
end

zip_sum([ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 10, 20, 30 ])
# => [ 11, 22, 33 ]

zip_sum(nil, [ 5, 6, 7 ])
# => [ 5, 6, 7 ]
```

The way `zip_sum` works is by "zipping" the two arrays together using [`Enumerable#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) (e.g. `[1, 2].zip([10, 20])` returns `[ [1, 10], [2, 20] ]`), then adding each pair together.

#### Step 2

Next, let's use [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) to get the parts of the data we care about:

```ruby
result1 = arr.flat_map do |item|
  item[:report_data].map {|datum| datum.values_at(:type, :data) }
end
```

```ruby
# result1 =>
[ [ { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" }, [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ] ],
  [ { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" },       [ 20, 30, 40, 50 ] ],
  [ { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" }, [ 15, 25, 35, 45 ] ],
  [ { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" },       [ 25, 35, 45, 55 ] ],
  [ { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" }, [ 17, 27, 37, 47 ] ],
  [ { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" },       [ 27, 37, 47, 57 ] ]
]
```

Above we've just grabbed the `:type` and `:data` values out of each hash the `:report_data` arrays.

#### Step 3

Next let's use [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) to iterate over the array of arrays and calculate a running sum of the `:data` values using the `zip_sum` method we defined earlier:

```ruby
result2 = result1.reduce({}) do |sums, (type, data)|
  sums.merge(type => data) do |_, old_data, new_data|
    zip_sum(old_data, new_data)
  end
end
```

```ruby
# result2 =>
{ { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" } => [ 42,  72, 102, 132 ],
  { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" }       => [ 72, 102, 132, 162 ]
}
```

The result might look a little odd to you because we usually use strings or symbols as hash keys, but in this hash we're using other hashes (the `:type` values from above) as keys. That's one nice thing about Ruby: You can use any object as a key in a hash.

Inside the `reduce` block, `sums` is the hash that's ultimately returned. It starts out as an empty hash (`{}`, the value we passed to `reduce` as an argument). `type` is the hash we're using as a key and `data` is the array of integers. In each iteration the next values from the `result2` array are assigned to `type`, but `sums` is updated with whatever value was returned at the end of the block in the previous iteration.

We're using [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) in kind of a tricky way:

```ruby
sums.merge(type => data) do |_, old_data, new_data|
  zip_sum(old_data, new_data)
end
```

This merges the hash `{ type => data }` (remember that `type` is the `:type` hash
 and `data` is the array of integers) into the hash `sums`. If there are any key collisions, the block will be invoked. Since we only have one key, `type`, then the block will be invoked if `sums[type]` already exists. If it does, we call `zip_sum` with the previous value of `sums[type]` and `data`, effectively keeping a running sum of `data`.

In effect, it's basically doing this:

```ruby
sums = {}

type, data = result2[0]
sums[type] = zip_sum(sums[type], data)

type, data = result2[1]
sums[type] = zip_sum(sums[type], data)

type, data = result2[3]
# ...and so on.
```

#### Step 4

We now have this hash in `result3`:

```ruby
{ { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" } => [ 42,  72, 102, 132 ],
  { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" }       => [ 72, 102, 132, 162 ]
}
```

That's the data we want, so now we just have to take it out of this weird format and put it into a regular hash with the keys `:type` and `:data`:

```ruby
result3 = result2.map {|type, data| { type: type, data: data } }
```

```ruby
# result3 =>
[ { type: { "id" => 1, "name" => "electricity" },
    data: [ 42, 72, 102, 132 ]
  },
  { type: { "id" => 2, "name" => "water" },
    data: [ 72, 102, 132, 162 ]
  }
]
```